# How to check if owner in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make this command where only the owner can run it. Is there anyway to check for the highest role or the creator of the server?

I tried '@commands.is_owner()' but that only checks if someone is the owner of the bot.

Comment: You can get the discord owner with the discord object. Just check if this is also the author.

Comment: You can use the `@commands.has_role(role_id)` decorator. This requires the user to have a specified role to be able to run the command.

Answer (score 3):

[`Guild.owner`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=owner#discord.Guild.owner) exists, so here's an example of its use!

```py
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your_prefix")

# example use with custom decorator
def guild_owner_only():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.author == ctx.guild.owner  # checks if author is the owner

    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command()
@guild_owner_only()
async def ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the decorator:

```py
@commands.has_role("RoleName")
```

Example:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.core import command

@bot.command
@commands.has_role("RoleName")
async def ...(ctx)
    await ctx.send("your message")
```

Let me know if it works!

Edit: you can also import everything:

```py
import discord
from discord import user
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands.core import command
from discord.member import Member
from discord.message import Message
from discord.user import User
```